# AWS CodeDeploy Duplicate permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to set permissions in my appspec.yml file, but I keep getting an error about duplicate permission settings when I run a deployment

> Duplicate permission setting instructions for
>   /data/html/httpdocs/artisan

This is currently (with except in list format) how the permission object is configured in my appspec.yml, per this [threads](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=590076&#590076) recommendation . I actually have multiple files I want different permissions on, but I can't seem to get it to work w/ just one file? what is the correct way?

```
permissions:
  - object: /data/html/httpdocs/ 
    pattern: "**"
    except: [/data/html/httpdocs/artisan]
    owner: ubuntu
    group: www-data
    mode: 644
    type:
      - file
  - object: /data/html/httpdocs/artisan
    owner: ubuntu
    group: www-data
    mode: 755
    type:
      - file
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran in to a similar issue and I ended up having to dig in to the codedeploy-agent source code.

The (poorly documented) except option for the CodeDeploy permissions currently accepts an array of **relative** filenames. You should be able to match your artisan file like this:

```
  permissions:
  - object: /data/html/httpdocs/ 
    pattern: "**"
    except: [artisan]
    owner: ubuntu
    group: www-data
    mode: 644
    type:
      - file
  - object: /data/html/httpdocs/artisan
    owner: ubuntu
    group: www-data
    mode: 755
    type:
      - file
```

Note that this will not work for folders or files nested within folders. You can use wildcards, but they will only match exceptions for the root directory of that object.

I had to move some of my scripts from a subfolder to the root because of this.

[Here's a link](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/blob/master/lib/instance_agent/codedeploy_plugin/application_specification/linux_permission_info.rb#L70) to the relevent codedeploy-agent code.