# Duplicate permission setting instructions CodeDeploy

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to use CodeDeploy to deploy an application onto EC2 but I am facing the following error

> Duplicate permission setting instructions for /var/www/html/storage/framework

My appspec.yml is below

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
 - source: /
   destination: /var/www/html

permissions:
  - object: /var/www/html
    owner: apache
    group: apache
    mode: 644
    except:
      - storage/*
    type:
      - directory
  - object: /var/www/html/storage
    owner: apache
    group: apache
    mode: 777
    type:
      - directory
```

I've tried various formats for `except` including

- Explicitly listing relative paths

  ```
  except:
   - storage
   - storage/app
   - storage/logs
   - storage/framework
   - storage/framework/views
   - storage/framework/cache
   - storage/framework/sessions
  ```
- Using a wildcard

  ```
  except:
   - storage/*
  ```
- Using just the folder name

  ```
  except:
   - storage
  ```

None of which seem to resolve the issue.

Similar questions

- [AWS CodeDeploy Duplicate permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413067/aws-codedeploy-duplicate-permission)
- [Duplicate permission setting instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881884/duplicate-permission-setting-instructions)

Comment: Why chmod 777?  Doing that ever should give you chills.  If the owner is apache, 755 should be appropriate.  No need to allow other apps and services access to there also, especially because it's a web site there publicly accessible.  Not that this is necessarily likely, but why not set the permissions properly?  Also, on aws your going to have a bad time of your assets are stored locally: even if you use EBS, that can fail, and you'll have no way of recovering your content.  I recommend you consider s3 instead.

Comment: 777 was a bi-product of experimenting. Rule out ownership issues etc while I'm fiddling with getting CodeDeploy to actually work. I already use S3 for files and, and Redis for sessions and caching. That said, the framework still requires the ability to write to that folder for various other compiled files and as such I need to change the permissions on the folder.

Comment: Well, I like testing against the security settings I want to use in production, personally.  
That makes me realize something else, though: you have /var/www/html set to mode 644 which _doesn't_ give apache permission to execute the directory, ie list its contents.  So you may want to consider adjusting those permissions to 5xx or 7xx, depending on whether you want Apache to be able to write to /var/www/html ( currently your settings allow writing and reading but not executing, so adding the exec bit woudl be 7, but if apache isn't supposed to write to /var/www/html, 5 would be correct )

Comment: It shouldn't be able to write to anything except the storage folder. It'll be above the docroot. `/var/www/html/site/public/` will be the docroot. I'm not testing production settings yet I'm literally just trying to get it to set some permissions so I can understand how it works on a bog standard AMI with no tweaks. I don't even intend to use Apache, it's just an exercise on how to get CodeDeploy to function at this point.

Comment: That makes more sense then.  Would it be possible  try a config where the 2 sources didn't overlap?  Based on what you're saying, could /var/ww/storage be used rather than something under /var/www/html?  Just a thought, might be interesting to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

The except option needs to be specified as an array. (Use `[]` not a nested list)

You can see it in the permissions examples in the appspec reference guide (scroll down a little): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html#app-spec-ref-permissions

Comment: I have tried this too, just forgot to list it. That was actually the first thing I tried because of the docs. Unfortunately it makes no difference. I thought however that `[]` and `- ` were equivalent in YAML - block style vs flow style under [generic sequences](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2802665)?

Comment: I concur, those are equivalent in yaml.  I use them both all the time.